# How do resend HTTP POST request with cpprest-sdk?

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

Given a HTTP POST request with a body, constructed somewhere else in the codebase, how can I resend the request in case of failures, like HTTP 401 Negotiation?

`web::http::http_request req(web::http::methods::POST)`

I have read that it's only safe to send POST/PUT once, as it's not possible to resubmit the body (due to streams?)